# Laravel Horizon not showing jobs

Tags: laravel

On a new Laravel 8 project my jobs are not appearing in the Horizon UI. Here's what I did:

- Install horizon and did `php artisan horizon:install`
- Configured the Redis queue driver
- When I do `php artisan horizon` the output shows that it's successfully processing jobs
- If I check my Redis database I can see the completed jobs being stored there (and failed jobs are stored in the mysql table)

So everything is working as expected.

The problem is that the Horizon interface does not show anything, it just shows the loading state everywhere. I've ran `php artisan optimize:clear` to make sure that it has the latest ENV and config settings but that didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK party people, here's what went down. In `config/horizon.php` you can set Horizon's `path`. I've just learned that you should not start this path with a `/`, because then Horizon's API calls to fetch the job data will fail.

**Don't use**

```
'path' => '/subfolder/horizon'
```

**Do use**

```
'path' => 'subfolder/horizon'
```